# Azure AD - Custom login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I am exploring Azure Active Directory. I am trying to see whether I can use my own login page with custom user id/password controls to capture the user credentials and validate against Azure AD. Whatever documentation that I came across and tried out, I ended up the unauthenticated user getting redirected to Azure Login page and entering the credentials there to validate, and then getting redirected back to my application upon authentication. Is it possible to develop my own login page and use some APIs to complete the authentication?

I am using the below configurations along with OWIN middleware, in an ASP.NET MVC web applicaiton.

```
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="22***************"/>
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/32*************" />
    <add key="ida:Logout" value="http://localhost:52942/Login/Logout"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to sign in a user with the username and password flow as noted [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/).

However this flow is very limited, and really should not be used outside of testing. One of the big takeaways for users who use a trusted identity manager is that they only want to share their username and password with a trusted party, like Microsoft. In general, consumers do not, and should not, feel comfortable typing in passwords for other systems into your custom website.

When we redirect users away from your website, and then redirect them back after authentication, we ensure to the user that no security details was every given to your site, and thus nothing can be mishandled.

Comment: Thanks. I get an error "Parsing WS-Trust response failed" on AcquireTokenAsync call. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a valid point, but wouldn't the workflow at hand be valid if the AD and the website are managed by the same person and just want to create one account to enable/disable when employees come and go?